# Diffeomorphism and causality

Tags: general-relativity, causality, diffeomorphism-invariance

Say you have to events A and B such that A is in the future light cone of B. Now say you apply a diffeomorphism transformation $x\rightarrow f(x)$ on the space-time, smoothly transforming the background, such that B is now in the future light cone of A.

How can this be? Which happened first A or B?

Since in GR a diffeomorphism transformation  is equivalent to a change in the gravitational field, what type of gravitational field does this represent? Some kind of time loop?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "a diffeomorphism is equivalent to a change in the gravitational field", and how could applying a diffeomorphism change the causal relations between two points? Do you mean that the diffeomorphism is such that the *image* of B under it is in the future of the *image* of A?

Comment: I just mean a coordinate transformation $x\rightarrow f(x)$. GR is invariant under these transformations. But what if point $x_1$ is transformed so it is now in the future of $x_2$ ? The metric is transformed as $df(x)/dx df(x)/dx g(x)$.

Comment: A coordinate transformation (which is *not* the same as a diffeomorphism of the manifold!)  does not change [causal structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure) - the causal structure, in particular the "future-ness" of events with respect to each other, is a property of the manifold together with a choice of time-orientation, not of any particular coordinate system.

Comment: But isn't a coordinate transformation $f$ which is invertible and smooth the same as a diffeomorphism? Maybe I'm thinking in terms of quantum gravity instead of classical gravity.

Comment: The distinction ACuriousMind is trying to draw is between passive and active transformations. A coordinate transformation is typically considered to be passive. What you are trying to do is something active. If you actively map the future light cone to the past light cone, naturally you will have changed the causal structure of your spacetime. However, changing coordinates on your future light cone doesn't spoil anything.

Comment: But you can stretch the manifold as long as you also change the metric of space-time to compensate. So what if you stretch it so A appears to B in the future of A? And then interpret the metric as a gravitational field, it looks like some strange gravitational effect that sends signals to the past! I must be missing something somewhere..

Comment: The point is that by actively deforming your spacetime, you are likely to change all manner of things, and this is not a problem. If I take 1+1-dimensional Minkowski spacetime and just rotate the whole thing round by 180 degrees, suddenly what was the future becomes the past. Of course it does! And what? This is not the same as choosing different coordinates in a given region of spacetime and seeing that different gravitational fields arise – in this case, I'm not actually making a change to the spacetime itself.

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate answers:

First, spacetime is not just a Lorentzian manifold; it is a Lorentzian manifold *together with a time orientation*.  So the relevant symmetry group is not the diffeomorphism group; it is the subgroup consisting of diffeomorphisms that preserve the time orientation.

But second:  A time-reversing diffeomorphism, while it does not preserve the structure of spacetime, **does** transform your spacetime into another, equally respectable spacetime (though perhaps one that is less in accordance with your preconceptions about what  matches reality).  This would be a spacetime exactly like our own, except that we choose to **define** the order of events so that breakfast comes after lunch instead of before.  That's a different spacetime, but you might not want to think of it as so **very** different.

Answer (score 3):

@Soledenon is absolutely right. Easy to show. A diffeomorphism takes x's to y's and g's to (say for notational simplicity) h. Then invariance means $$ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$$does not change when g changes to h and x to y. Then since $ds^2=0$ is invariant the null cones are the same, and a curve that was inside remains inside and those outside remain outside. Causality is not coordinate dependent.

If that was not true analyzing causal structures would have no answer nor meaning. Penrose's book on the causal structure of spacetime shows great ways in which the causal structure is easier to see, basically coordinate systems where light rays go at plus/minus 45 degree angles wrt to the axis. The structure is the same, if a light ray never was able to leave a black hole in any one coordinate system, it never could in the 45 degree slanted rays coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of the "future light cone" is background independent. This means that it is determined by the physical content: by fields over the spacetime manifold. Without the metric field you don't have the concept of causality.

When you apply a diffeomorphism, the metric field gets transformed so that the causal relation remains intact.

Bottom line: causality is an absolute physical concept, it is diffeomorphism-invariant. There is no way you can reverse a causal relation by a diffeomorphism.

**UPD:** this only holds for diffeomorphisms from the connected component of the diffeomorphism group containing the identity transformation.

Comment: "There is no way you can reverse a causal relation by a diffeomorphism".  This is obviously false.  Consider (1+1) dimensional Minkowski space, with a basis where $(0,1)$ is spacelike and $(1,0)$ is timelike.  Then the map $(a,b)\mapsto (-a,b)$ is a diffeomorphism that reverses causality.

Comment: @WillO you're right, I was wrong. What I meant was: diffeomorphisms which lie in the connected component of the diffeomorphism group which includes the identity diffeomorphism can't change causality.